# how do I "unload" a GridView on my ASP .NET web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

when the page starts, I cannot SEE the GridView even though it's set to "visible."

I only see it after data has been loaded into it.

After data has been loaded into it, how can I "unload" it? Meaning, how can I make it disappear the same way it was BEFORE data was bound to it?

Comment: Hide the gridview's `<table>` element from the client side?

Comment: Couldn't you just set `Visible = false`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I get your question but something like this would empty the grid on server side

```
gridView1.DataSource = null;
gridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for. i set the datasource to null but i forgot to databind. i can accept in 5 mins.

Comment: Because I had to wait 5 minutes to do it. What's the rush?

Comment: @Clever Idea Widgetry: the site force users to wait at least 15 minutes to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

On page load do this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            gridView1.DataSource = string.Empty;
            gridView1.DataBind();
        }
}
```

Oh and set the show header when empty property of the grid view in your aspx:

```
ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
```